# Windows XP will not boot after installing Ubuntu

Tags: windows

I followed the installation directions for Ubuntu to windows XP. After install was complete the computer would not reboot. Andy suggestions?

Comment: Did you install it via Wubi or you made a clean install?

Comment: possible duplicated: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/q/88384/62483)

Comment: More information is needed. Release of Ubuntu, how you installed (as mentioned in another comment), also describe what happened when the *computer would not reboot*, add details of your computer specs (brand/model/graphics card/wifi etc). Please edit your questions with this information. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply open a terminal and give this command:

`sudo update-grub`

With this command, grub will find your Windows XP Partition.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

and add windows to the list, it will be shown at the next restart